# How to toggle window position in vim

Tags: vim

To move a window around I can do:

<kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>w</kbd> <kbd>shift</kbd><kbd>H, J, K, or L</kbd>

Is there a way to just toggle the position of the windows? For example, pressing it five times would do:

- <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>w</kbd> <kbd>shift</kbd><kbd>K</kbd>
- <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>w</kbd> <kbd>shift</kbd><kbd>L</kbd>
- <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>w</kbd> <kbd>shift</kbd><kbd>J</kbd>
- <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>w</kbd> <kbd>shift</kbd><kbd>H</kbd>
- <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>w</kbd> <kbd>shift</kbd><kbd>K</kbd>

Is there something like that in vim, or I have to specify the direction explicitly when repositioning the window?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems there's no such a thing in Vim (maybe some plugin exists, though). If there was, we would have found it described at `:help window-moving`.

On the other hand, you can create your own mapping to handle this. The following, for instance, works as you require:

```
nnoremap <C-W><C-X> :call NextPost()<CR>
let g:mydic = {0: 'K', 1: 'L', 2: 'J', 3: 'H'}
let g:nextPosIndex = -1
function! NextPost()
  if g:nextPosIndex == 3
    let g:nextPosIndex = 0
  else
    let g:nextPosIndex += 1
  endif
  execute "normal! \<C-W>" . g:mydic[g:nextPosIndex]
endfunction
```

Note that the counter `g:nextPosIndex` is never reset, so after a `K` movement happened on a window, if you move *to* another window, and then move it, it will `L`-move.¹

[1] Based on D. Ben Knoble's comment, this limitation seems to be easly removed by using window-local variable `w:nextPosIndex` instead of a global one, `g:nextPosIndex`.

Comment: You could use a window-local (w:)

Comment: Thanks, @D.BenKnoble! Btw, in case you haven't noticed, I have posted a possibly interesting [question on vi&Vim beta](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/24686/any-reason-why-one-should-avoid-to-force-the-linking-of-highlight-groups-in-synt)...

Comment: @EnricoMariaDeAngelis thanks for this great answer. By the way, to learn basic vim scripting, is there a recommended book or tutorial as a starting place?

Comment: @David542, [Learn Vimscript the Hard Way](http://learnvimscriptthehardway.stevelosh.com/) is well considered by a lot of people, including me. [Learning the vi and vim Editors](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596529833.do) is very good for vi& Vim, and also has **some** chapters dedicated to Vim scripting.